# MPU6050 DMP does not work?

Tags: arduino

I'm using DMP and It generates this error

```
  Send any character to begin DMP programming and demo: 
  Initializing DMP...
  DMP Initialization failed (code 1)
```

Any help would be appreciated :)
Thanks

Comment: With the information given, it's extremely unlikely anyone will be able to help you.  Post everything you can to help us help you.  Is power connected?  Do you have an MPU6050?  Is it wired into the circuit?

Comment: Thanks for replying me..I have connect power SDA,SCL,INT,PWR,GND of MPU6050 to arduino MEGA.I have used Jeff Rowberg's DMP6 code and it generated this problem.

Comment: Provide everything means, everything. Not a description of the pins on the breakout board.
Please state which pins on the Mega you connected it to, which code you are using, which breakout board you got.

Answer (score 6):

The first thing to check is that the i2c device is connected properly. A good way to do this is to use the [i2c scanner](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner). You should see the mpu6050 on 0x68 or 0x69 depending on whether the address pin is pulled low or high.

If you see it, but still can't connect, make sure your library is set up to use the correct address.

From there I find it easiest to try the raw readings first. If you can read the accels and gyros raw, you are ready to try DMP.

Comment: My problem was that SCK pin was not properly soldered to ATmega pin 28 ! Thank you for that i2c scanner routine

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you provide info, we can talk on a common basis.
Before that, I assume you use a "copy and paste" code of i2c-devlib's code.
Therefore, the first error one could make is to forget to set up an interrupt handler in code for the interrupt of the FIFO buffer.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, connect your MPU-6050 to 3.3V as it is designed to work with "Voltage - Supply:2.375 V ~ 3.46 V".